# Cannot access __skb_buff in eBPF

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I am trying to access the `__sk_buff` struct passed within the `consume_skb` tracepoint. However nothing I tried has worked so far. I am running the kernel version `5.4.0`. This is what I tried so far, and in what it resulted:

**Loader**
[gist](https://gist.github.com/marxlaml/2edff67b8178d5ac385d572efec8c732)

**Direct access**

```c
SEC("tracepoint/skb/consume_skb")
int handle_skb(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    struct iphdr *iph = data + sizeof(*eth);

    if (data + sizeof(*eth) > data_end)
        return 0;

    if (data + sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*iph) > data_end)
        return 0;

    bpf_trace_printk("%x\n", eth->h_proto);

    return 0;
}
```

results in:

```
libbpf: prog 'handle_skb': BPF program load failed: Permission denied
libbpf: prog 'handle_skb': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
; void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
0: (61) r2 = *(u32 *)(r1 +76)
; void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
1: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r1 +80)
; struct iphdr *iph = data + sizeof(*eth);
2: (bf) r3 = r2
3: (07) r3 += 14
; if (data + sizeof(*eth) > data_end)
4: (2d) if r3 > r1 goto pc+7
 R1_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R2_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R3_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=14,umax_value=4294967309,var_off=(0x0; 0x1ffffffff)) R10=fp0
;
5: (bf) r3 = r2
6: (07) r3 += 34
; if (data + sizeof(*eth) > data_end)
7: (2d) if r3 > r1 goto pc+4
 R1_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R2_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R3_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=34,umax_value=4294967329,var_off=(0x0; 0x1ffffffff)) R10=fp0
; bpf_trace_printk("%x\n", eth->h_proto);
8: (69) r2 = *(u16 *)(r2 +12)
R2 invalid mem access 'inv'
processed 9 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'handle_skb'
libbpf: failed to load object 'skb_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'skb_bpf': -13
Failed to load and verify BPF skeleton
```

The way I understand it, is that direct access to `skb` is not allowed in this context (why?).

**bpf_skb_load_bytes**

```c
SEC("tracepoint/skb/consume_skb")
int handle_skb(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct ethhdr *eth;

    int ret;
    ret = skb_load_bytes(skb, 0, eth, sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    //Or alternatively
    //ret = bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, 0, eth, sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    if (!ret)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bpf_trace_printk("%x\n", eth->h_proto);

    return 0;
}
```

which results in:

```
libbpf: prog 'handle_skb': BPF program load failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: prog 'handle_skb': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
; ret = bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, 0, eth, sizeof(struct ethhdr));
0: (b7) r2 = 0
1: (b7) r4 = 14
2: (85) call bpf_skb_load_bytes#26
unknown func bpf_skb_load_bytes#26
processed 3 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'handle_skb'
libbpf: failed to load object 'skb_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'skb_bpf': -22
Failed to load and verify BPF skeleton
```

This confuses me even more, as `bpf_skb_load_bytes` should be an available helper function.

Now I am doubting how to even access and read (not even write) the `__sk_buff`.
Is there just no way? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Could you add the kernel version you are using and the commands used to compile and insert the filter? By the way you should use `struct ethhdr eth;` (not a pointer) and pass `&eth`, otherwise you are writing through an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: I added both to the original post. I also fixed the `&eth` thingy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. First is that the argument to the tracepoint is of type [`struct sk_buff`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.6/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L880), not [`struct __sk_buff`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.6/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L5543). I believe you have to use the`bpf_probe_read` helper to read memory the pointer is pointing to.

Second is that `bpf_skb_load_bytes` would only work with a `__sk_buff`. Besides, not all helpers are available for each program type, tracing programs can't use the `bpf_skb_load_bytes` helper. Here is the code that lists all available helpers for tracepoint programs:

- https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.1/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L1415
- https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.1/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L1167

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `bpf_probe_read` (along with everything else) was the solution to my problem.

Comment: Quick question about the argument, how do you know of which type it is? `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/skb/consume_skb/format` shows something different. And when I handle the argument as a `sk_buff` every entry is 0.

Comment: I get back `field:void * skbaddr; offset:8; size:8; signed:0;`. The definition for this is created here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.7/source/include/trace/events/skb.h#L109. You can see from the source code that a `struct sk_buff*` is passed.